# Identification of invertebrate

Tags: species-identification

Found on mattresses/walls in France. Size about 3mm long.

[image: seen from above]

[image: turned over]

Comment: The duplicate suggestion unfortunately gives the answer. Leaving you, some cleaning to be done.... sigh